# SVN revprop in git-svn

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I have repository in SVN (due to some business reasons I cannot switch fully to git) but I locally prefer to use git with git-svn. But because of CI configuration I need to set custom revprops during commit

```
svn ci --with-revprop ARG=value
```

It seams git-svn does not support it, I would like to ask if someone have any clever workaround? Is it possible add revprops to dcommit like:

```
git svn dcommit --with-revprop ARG=value
```

Comment: I guess if you change the implementation of dcommit. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to modify the [git-svn.perl](https://github.com/git/git/blob/217f2767cbcb562872437eed4dec62e00846d90c/git-svn.perl) script, more precisely the [`dcommit` options part](https://github.com/git/git/blob/217f2767cbcb562872437eed4dec62e00846d90c/git-svn.perl#L185-L198) in order to add `--with-revprop`

Then you would use that option in [`sub cmd_dcommit`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/217f2767cbcb562872437eed4dec62e00846d90c/git-svn.perl#L845).